# Video with DRM can't be played, suddenly stop working but it works sometimes after re-login in Ubuntu

Tags: video-player, drm

I'm experiencing a strange behavior.

Sometimes every video can't be played or stop working after a while, without any apparent reason.

After a session logout and login, it come back working.

When it stop working, it stop working on Firefox, Chrome and in Udemy, YouTube, and in every video with DRM content: the video does not start, I can see only the first preview frame.

No error is displayed by Ubuntu.

In the Udemy check page, it says all is ok.

I already have the latest versions, using a Lenovo laptop and a 5G WiFi connection.

How to fix it so it always works?

Is there any DRM package to update in Ubuntu?

Thanks